# Guard clause in Rails if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I am using Rubocop in my application and it suggests `Use a guard clause instead of wrapping the code inside a conditional expression` for this. Plz suggest a clean way to rewrite it.

```
 if (geolocation_points.exists? || geolocation_boxes.exists?)
  self.geolocation = true
 end
```

Comment: Is the code you provided an entire method body? Is the example given in http://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/rubocop/Rubocop/Cop/Style/GuardClause not sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that code is in a method you would write a guard condition like so:

```
def my_fancy_method
  return unless geolocation_points.exists? && geolocation_boxes.exists?
  self.geolocation = true
end
```

However, if `geolocation` should always either be true or false, I would probably write it as follows, which works without an if or a guard condition:

```
def my_fancy_method
  self.geolocation = geolocation_points.exists? && geolocation_boxes.exists?
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I do have it within a method and use || (OR) condition in my case.